# .select2 and json.parse() not working in IE

Tags: json

$(".Test").select2(
        {
            placeholder: 'Enter name',
            data: JSON.parse(data_val)
        });
I am using .select2 and json for dropdown.
In all other browser its working fine except in IE. Its giving error as 
"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'attr': object is null or undefined 
select2.min.js?token=, line 21 character 2751"

Any workaround is helpful.

Thanks

Comment: did you any work around on it? I'm getting same issue?